How would you say "Because a college degree set you apart thirty years ago, that means it still does now." in Latin?
My attempt would be "Quoniam diploma te distinguebat abhinc triginta annos, id significat eam etiamnunc te distinguere.".

Your English sentence is ungrammatical to me, and I would be wary of carrying that through into the Latin. Possibly better to rephrase it as "If a college degree &c.".
